# How to get the environment object from the environment string?

Tags: r, scope, namespaces, scoping

Let's say I create a function:

```
x = function() { print(environmentName(environment())); envir=environment(); print(envir); print(environmentName(envir)); print(environmentName(environment())); print(environmentName(as.environment(environment()))); print(environmentName(parent.env(environment()))); envir; }
```

On my computer it prints out a unique hash of the environment in only **one** instance.  That leads to a fundamental question about what is an `envir` and how the function `environmentName(envir)` actually works.

For example,

```
( env = x() );
```

outputs:

```
> ( env = x() );
[1] ""
<environment: 0x000001fec97c3eb0>
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] "R_GlobalEnv"
<environment: 0x000001fec97c3eb0>
```

and reports an "" EMPTY environment name:

```
> environmentName(env)
[1] ""
```

When I was expecting a string `"0x000001fec97c3eb0"` or something.  I guess every time I call the function `x` I get a new environment.

```
> environmentName(x)
[1] ""
> environmentName(environment(x))
[1] "R_GlobalEnv"
```

### New environments

Maybe unless it is "FIXED" to a package or attached as an environment?
From ([How to get environment of a variable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583211/))

```
a <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
a$x <- 3
attach(a)
b <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
b$x <- 4
```

This yields:

```
environmentName(a);
environmentName(b);
```

both EMPTY "" ???

It does seem to work on the following, called from GLOBAL:

```
> environmentName(environment());
[1] "R_GlobalEnv"
```

So there appears to be a fundamental question:

### Fundament Question:  How exactly does `environmentName` work?

But that was not my primary question.  The above example is a function that has an `envir` as an input and returns a string.  How can I reverse that process.  That is, if I have a stringname `R_GlobalEnv` how do I return the `envir` R object?

### Primary Question:  Is there a function that reverses the logic of `environmentName`?

That is, if I have a stringname of the `environmentName`, what function do I call to reverse it?  Or what function can be written to enhance the `R` experience?

e.g.,

```
env.toName = function(envir=environment()) { environmentName(envir); }
env.fromName = function(envirstr) { XXVXX(envirstr); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all environments have names, which is why you see `""` sometimes.  `environmentName(env)` just returns the `"name"` attribute of `env`.

There is no standard function that can take the name and return the environment:  to write one, you'd have to search all variables in view for the environments, then individually check for a name on each.  You might find more than one with the same name attribute, e.g.

```r
a <- new.env()
attr(a, "name") <- "myenv"
b <- new.env()
attr(b, "name") <- "myenv"
environmentName(a)
#> [1] "myenv"
environmentName(b)
#> [1] "myenv"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Names on environments are there just as decoration, not for unique identification.  Check for equality using `identical()`:

```
d <- a
environmentName(d)
#> [1] "myenv"
identical(a, b)
#> [1] FALSE
identical(a, d)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: It seems like you are saying that the function is just getting the `name` attribute?  If that were the case, how do I get the `TRUE` environment name from an environment object `<environment: 0x000001fec97c3eb0>` ... How to extract the `0x000001fec97c3eb0` as a string?  The question then would be the reverse.  If I had the string `0x000001fec97c3eb0`, could I get the function name?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "true" environment name.  What you see is just the way environment objects are printed when they don't have a name, and aren't one of a few special ones.  I believe it's the hex value of the C pointer to the environment, but at R level, there is no way to work directly with C pointers.  If you write code in C you might be able to use it, but it's very tricky to know whether it remains valid at some future time.   Just assign the environment to an R variable, and work with that.